# Add custom url action parameter to django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms, url-pattern

The common url action parameters in django-cms are for example: `?edit` to enter Edit-mode, `?toolbar_off` to disable/hide the toolbar.

Now I'd like to add a new action parameter e.g. `?logout` which just logs out the user no matter on which url he/she currently is. I'd tried to include this in the `urls.py` with the following pattern:

```
    url(r'^.*\?logout$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin/logout/')),
```

I read in another SO answer that you shouldn't catch URL Params with an url pattern...

Should I do this in a kind of middleware? Or where else?

*Using django==1.11, django-cms==3.5.3*

Answer (score 1):

This should definily go into a middleware. It would probably work as well as an url pattern, but is kind of not "how you do it" - at least I never saw anything like it in a tutorial or documentation.